# Using python's print("""\""")

Tags: python

I'm currently reading the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html) and I've stumbled upon this:

> String literals can span multiple lines. One way is using triple-quotes: """...""" or '''...'''. End of lines are automatically included in the string, but it’s possible to prevent this by adding a \ at the end of the line. The following example:
>
> > ```
> > print("""\
> > Usage: thingy [OPTIONS]  
> >  -h                        Display this usage message
> >  -H hostname               Hostname to connect to     
> > """)
> > ```

I'm just not understanding what role `\` plays here. I know my question is a bit basic, but does anyone have an example that plays out differently depending on the use of `\` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it!

```
>>> print("""\
... Usage: x
... """)
Usage: x

>>> print("""
... Usage: x
... """)

Usage: x
```

The `\` at the end of the first line prevents the output from starting with a blank line, because, as you quoted:

> End of lines are automatically included in the string

except if they have been escaped with `\`.

Comment: Perfect, I missed that small detail when testing, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The `\` is used to negate end of line. In this case new line character

**Code:**

```
print("""\
Usage: thingy [OPTIONS] \
-h                        Display this usage message\
-H hostname               Hostname to connect to \
""")
```

**Output:**

```
Usage: thingy [OPTIONS]  -h                        Display this usage message -H hostname               Hostname to connect to
```

Now without negating new line characters

**Code1:**

```
print("""\
Usage: thingy [OPTIONS]  
-h                        Display this usage message
-H hostname               Hostname to connect to     
""")
```

**Output1:**

```
Usage: thingy [OPTIONS]  
-h                        Display this usage message
-H hostname               Hostname to connect to
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\` at the beginning is to ensure that there is no newline at the start. It essentially takes the new line as its own escape character, so it does not turn it into `'\n'` (newline):

```
>>> print("""\ 
... Hello""")
Hello
>>> print("""
... Hello""")
                  <-- Notice the newline
Hello
>>>
```

So putting the backslash before is like putting no gap at all.

The following to sections of code produce the same result:

```
>>> print("""Hello
... World""")
Hello
World
>>> print("""\
... Hello
... World""")
Hello
World
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply makes it ignore the new line within that string. For example, with it my output is

```
"Usage: thingy [OPTIONS]
 -h                        Display this usage message
 -H hostname               Hostname to connect to"
```

However, without it my output is

```
"

Usage: thingy [OPTIONS]
 -h                        Display this usage message
 -H hostname               Hostname to connect to"
```